# Why do I get upside-down image?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement ifft2 by computing the individual dot product instead of matrix  mutliplication ( I understand it is computationlly extremely intensive). The image constructed from the individual dot product implementation is upside-down compare to the matrix multiplication-wise ifft2.  In the code below rA is the data.

Code  with matrix multiplication:

```
def DFT_matrix(N):
    i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))
    omega = np.exp( - 2 * np.pi * 1j / N )
    W = np.power( omega, i * j )/N
    return W
def forPyhton(v1,v2):
    weight=np.dot(v2,v1)
    return weight
    


rA=slice_kspace[5,:,:]
slice7=np.fft.ifft2(rA) 
slice7=np.fft.fftshift(slice7)

slices7Abs=np.abs(slice7)+1e-9

dftMtxM=np.conj(DFT_matrix(len(rA)))
dftMtxN=np.conj(DFT_matrix(len(rA[1])))

mA = dftMtxM @ rA @ dftMtxN
```

Individual dot producewise implementation:

```
def DFT_matrix(N):
    i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))
    omega = np.exp( - 2 * np.pi * 1j / N )
    W = np.power( omega, i * j )/N
    return W
def forPyhton(v1,v2):
    weight=np.dot(v2,v1)
    return weight
                
            
            
rA=slice_kspace[5,:,:]
slice7=np.fft.ifft2(rA) 
slice7=np.fft.fftshift(slice7)
slices7Abs=np.abs(slice7)+1e-9
dftMtxM=np.conj(DFT_matrix(len(rA)))
dftMtxN=np.conj(DFT_matrix(len(rA[1])))
#mA = dftMtxM @ rA @ dftMtxN
result=[]
for i in range(0,rA.shape[0]):
    row1=[]
    for j in range(0,dftMtxN.shape[1]):
        scaleWeight=forPyhton(rA[i,:],dftMtxN[:,j])


        row1.append(scaleWeight)

    result.append(row1)
result=np.asarray(result)
 
mA=[]
for i in range(0,dftMtxM.shape[0]):
    row2=[]
    for j in range(0,result.shape[1]):
        scaleWeight=forPyhton(dftMtxM[i,:],np.array(result[:,j]))

        row2.append(scaleWeight)
    mA.append(row2)
mm=np.amax(np.abs(mA))
mA=np.fft.fftshift(mA)
mAabs=np.abs(mA)+1e-9
```

The plotting of slices7Abs mA is done by

```
plt.figure(3)
plt.imshow(slices7Abs,cmap='gray',origin='lower')
plt.figure(4)
plt.imshow(mAabs,cmap='gray',origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

The figure 3 and figure 4 is same in case of method 1 i.e. for matrixwise multiplication but for the second case, with individual dot productwise implementation the image i.e figure 4 is upside-down. Any idea why the image is upside down?

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation of the `for` loops. I want don't want to make any assumptions about which lines belong in the loop and which don't.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your problem is. I tried running the code with `scipy.misc.ascent()` as input and all the methods agree. Could you provide the data for `slice_kspace` that you observe the problem with?

Comment: @mandulaj, Thank you for your comments. I can try to upload the images on  Monday as the computer is not with me now. Is the for loops got corrected?

Comment: @mandulaj, how can I add data here. The for loop should be correct now.

Comment: @mandulaj Is there a way to make the code faster by running the for loops in parallel. Further, I have observed that the image is not upside down but if I rotate my image twice by 90 degree than I get the required image.

Comment: How big is the data? You can upload it somewhere and share a link (Google Drive, Github)

Comment: Regarding the for loops, best way to speed up a for loop is to remove it. You can try using something like https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum or if can't be bothered to remove the loops, try pre compiling them with https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: @mandulaj This is a link to the data. Please let me know once you got it.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/14O17vnN5KdkudWP8QxAXbBrUffiudu1N/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The file is big and have many images. I will let you the one I am using.

Comment: Just upload one image for which you see the problem. Because I can't reproduce what you are claiming.

Comment: links https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UNzxcAJAutT2xSCgCpLirRG2a9gbA-t1/view?usp=sharing   https://drive.google.com/file/d/11DMrvfoxwqEbgNPKIB7Gwlv4QwDzUxTJ/view?usp=sharing    I will delete the other file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227502/discussion-between-mandulaj-and-creator).